# Private files aren't blocking direct access to image files

Tags: 7, nodes, users, files

I'm currently very confused by how private files work:

- I have a content type that has an image field and a file field.  Both
  are set up to use private file access for their contents.
- Node access on the content type is working correctly.
- A user who does not have access to the node cannot get to the contents of the file field -- they get an access_denied page when they try to load the URL of the file.
- However, they DO have access to the image file, via the image's url (/system/files/...): hitting the image URL in a browser brings it right up.

Are there any insights out there about why the image file is leaking through, and what I can do to stop it?   I've explored hook_file_download and hook_file_download_access, and have been putting watchdog statements throughout the image and files modules trying to track this down, but to no avail.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three implementations of [hook_file_download()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/implementations/hook_file_download/7), in Drupal:

- [file_file_download()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!file!file.module/function/file_file_download/7)
- [image_file_download()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.module/function/image_file_download/7)
- [user_file_download()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_file_download/7)

The first two implementations always check the user has access to the entity to which the file is associated; the third one doesn't check that, but it only checks the directory containing the file is the one used for the user profile's pictures.

```
function user_file_download($uri) {
  if (strpos(file_uri_target($uri), variable_get('user_picture_path', 'pictures') . '/picture-') === 0) {
    $info = image_get_info($uri);
    return array('Content-Type' => $info['mime_type']);
  }
}
```

If there isn't any other module implementing `hook_file_download()`, I would expect the users to be able to access the files through http://example.com/system/files when the URI points to the same directory containing the images used for the user accounts.

Comment: Yeah -- I had run into those functions while trying to figure out what was going on. What I found was that image_file_download was allowing access, down in the "Private file access for the original files" area. Also, btw, the files in question are not being saved in the user_picture_path directory.  Anyway, I put together a hook_file_download() handler that, by borrowing some code from image_file_download, checks the assigned node and does the right thing re access.  I'm still not sure why it's not just happening has part of the basic system; maybe I'm messing something up elsewhere.  Thx!